# No Bluetooth Hardware on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, 20.04, bluetooth, connection

I've HP Laptop, setup on Dual Boot with Windows 10.

Bluetooth works normally on Windows 10 but it doesn't seem to work on ubuntu. I read 100's of threads with no luck, finally posting a question here.

Terminal Output of some commands I tried:

```
> ● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
>      Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
>      Active: active (running) since Sat 2021-08-21 16:49:53 PKT; 13min ago
>        Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)    Main PID: 3439 (bluetoothd)
>      Status: "Running"
>       Tasks: 1 (limit: 9337)
>      Memory: 1.5M
>      CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
>              └─3439 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd
> 
> اگست 21 16:49:53 HaroonsLap systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
> اگست 21 16:49:53 HaroonsLap bluetoothd[3439]: Bluetooth daemon 5.53
> اگست 21 16:49:53 HaroonsLap systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
> اگست 21 16:49:53 HaroonsLap bluetoothd[3439]: Starting SDP server اگست
> 21 16:49:53 HaroonsLap bluetoothd[3439]: Bluetooth management
> interface 1.19 initialized

haroon@HaroonsLap:~$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

haroon@HaroonsLap:~$ sudo lshw | grep -A 10 "blue"
haroon@HaroonsLap:~$ sudo rmmod rtbth
rmmod: ERROR: Module rtbth is not currently loaded

haroon@HaroonsLap:~$ journalctl -xb | grep blue
اگست 21 16:48:46 HaroonsLap NetworkManager[1047]: <info>  [1629546526.1066] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-device-plugin-bluetooth.so)
اگست 21 16:48:47 HaroonsLap /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1232]: (II) modeset(0): blueX: 0.160 blueY: 0.135   whiteX: 0.313 whiteY: 0.329
اگست 21 16:48:47 HaroonsLap dbus-daemon[1046]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service' requested by ':1.36' (uid=1000 pid=1221 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=jo")
-- Subject: A start job for unit bluetooth.service has finished successfully
-- A start job for unit bluetooth.service has finished successfully.
اگست 21 16:49:02 HaroonsLap dbus-daemon[1237]: [session uid=1000 pid=1237] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez.obex' unit='dbus-org.bluez.obex.service' requested by ':1.89' (uid=1000 pid=2917 comm="gnome-control-center ")
اگست 21 16:49:02 HaroonsLap dbus-daemon[1237]: [session uid=1000 pid=1237] Successfully activated service 'org.bluez.obex'
اگست 21 16:49:12 HaroonsLap dbus-daemon[1046]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
اگست 21 16:49:53 HaroonsLap sudo[3426]:   haroon : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/haroon ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl restart bluetooth
-- Subject: A start job for unit bluetooth.service has begun execution
-- A start job for unit bluetooth.service has begun execution.
اگست 21 16:49:53 HaroonsLap bluetoothd[3439]: Bluetooth daemon 5.53
-- Subject: A start job for unit bluetooth.service has finished successfully
-- A start job for unit bluetooth.service has finished successfully.
اگست 21 16:49:53 HaroonsLap bluetoothd[3439]: Starting SDP server
اگست 21 16:49:53 HaroonsLap dbus-daemon[1046]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.87' (uid=0 pid=3439 comm="/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd ")
اگست 21 16:49:53 HaroonsLap bluetoothd[3439]: Bluetooth management interface 1.19 initialized
```

Comment: Not sure if related but disabling Fast Startup in Windows when dual-booting is a MUST. Try that to start with something. And please edit the question to post `lspci` results identifying your actual hardware.

Comment: I believe that most bluetooth hardware will be found in: `lsusb`